# I am unable to post the notifications

Tags: ios, swift3, nsnotificationcenter

I had searched stack over flow and all sites but unable to post notifications and I need to pass data from this class to another class I need to send the bool value to have validations can anyone help me how to pass the bool value ?

here is the code for it

```
        radioSelected = false
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(paymentRadioEnable(n:)), name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "notification"), object: nil)
        self.shippingmethodURL()
        shippingTableView.delegate = self
        shippingTableView.dataSource = self
        shippingTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        shippingTableView.estimatedRowHeight = shippingTableView.rowHeight
        // Initialization code
    }
    func paymentRadioEnable(n:NSNotification){

    }
    func paymentRadioAction(button : KGRadioButton) {
        _ = button.center
        let centralPoint = button.superview?.convert(button.center, to:self.shippingTableView)
        let indexPath =  self.shippingTableView.indexPathForRow(at: centralPoint!)
        if button.isSelected {

        } else{
            chekIndex = indexPath
            radioSelected = true
            self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

this is another class to which I need to post the bool value to check

```
@IBAction func continueButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notification"), object: nil)
            if radioSelected == false {
                let radiobutton = SCLAlertView()
                _ =  radiobutton.showError("Warning", subTitle: "Please select shipping method", closeButtonTitle: "OK")
            }else{
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let addtoCartVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "payment") as! PaymentMethodViewController
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addtoCartVC, animated: true)
            }
    }
```

Comment: Did the observer class been initialized?

Comment: how to know that observer initialised  ? @BalajiKondalrayal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the data into the object at the time of posting the Notification

> let data : NSDictionary = ["DataKey" : "DataValue"]
>
> NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue:
>   "notification"), object: data)

And after posting , you can get the same data in notification Handler.

Comment: I need to send true or false only not like NSDictionary fomat @Ajay Kokcha

Comment: I tend to interpret the NSNotification API as follows: `object` the sender of the notification (in this case, `self`), `userInfo` is the detailed information you intend to pass around (in this case, `data`). **However**, most of the time the sender doesn't really matter and the usage above is a sensible shortcut.

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaS In thay case, you can just pass your boolean as the `object` argument. The docs say ithe parameter is of type `Any?` in Swift, so it should accept a boolean constant.

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaS 

if you want to send only Bool value then you should send a bool variable like :

let boolVariable : Bool = true

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notification"), object: boolVariable)

Comment: how to add observer then to receive in another class ?@AjayKokcha

Comment: In your observer :

func paymentRadioEnable(n:NSNotification){
if let boolValue = n.object as? Bool {
            //do whatever you want to do with this Bool Value
        }
    }